# How to modify a specific div that shares class name with other divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this html :

```
<td class="score_section">
    <div class="row collapse" align="center">                    
       <div class="upvotebutton" onclick="javascript: Upvote()">▲</div>
       <div class="votescore"> 40 </div>
       <div class="donwvotebutton" onclick="javascript: Downvote()">▼</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

This is part of a table of products , so more rows have this class "votescore" , and I have made a jQuery(ajax) function for downvote/upvote :

```
function Upvote(user_id, thread_id) {
    var vote = +1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Ajax/vote-o-matic.php",
        data: {user_id: user_id, thread_id: thread_id, vote: vote},
        success: function(res) {
            jquery(this).$('.votescore').html(res);
        }
    });
}
```

After a successful downvote or upvote to refresh the specific "votescore" div (the one that coresponds with the upvote/downvote buttons) with the incoming data from ajax.

Everything works ok only for when I click it refreshes all "votescore" divs , any ideas to fix or around this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the listener which then allows you to reference the clicked element with `this`

```
$('.upvotebutton').on('click', function(){
    var me = $(this);
    var vote = +1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Ajax/vote-o-matic.php",
        data: {
            user_id: user_id,
            thread_id: thread_id,
            vote: vote
        },
        success: function (res) {
            me.parent().find('.votescore').html(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Extra step using .parent instead of .siblings

Comment: Where are the `user_id` and `thread_id` variables coming from? Your code (as shown) would throw an _undefined_ exception.

Comment: @MelanciaUK they were there in the OP's original snippet and seemed to be defined elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is that $(this).parent().find('.votescore').html(res); doesn't refresh the score

Comment: @Tiberiu don't you mean `me.parent().find('.votescore').html(res);` ?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker But doesn't `var me = $(this);` ? Is it of great importance to declare it ?

Comment: @Tiberiu Yes it is important as `$(this)` means different things in the different scopes.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker  I've tried declaring it just like in your answer , and with no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59369/discussion-between-tiberiu-and-rob-schmuecker).

Answer (score -1):

You should give it an ID, and then use it to refresh the div.

```
<td class="score_section" id="section1">
   <div class="row collapse" align="center">
       <div class="upvotebutton" onclick="javascript: Upvote(section1)">▲</div>
       <div class="votescore"> 40 </div>
       <div class="donwvotebutton" onclick="javascript: Downvote(section1)">▼</div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Then:

```
function Upvote(div_id,user_id, thread_id){
    var vote = +1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        ..
        success: function(res){
            $(div_id).html(res);
        }
    });
}
```